# Twitter4j.properties file not being read

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am unable to get my project to read in my `twitter4j.properties` file even though I have copied it to the root of the project folder in Eclipse. I have filled out the properties file according to the configuration guide like so:

```
oauth.consumerKey=thisismyconsumerkey
oauth.consumerSecret=thisismyconsumersecret
oath.accessToken=14778563-thisismyaccesstoken
oath.accessTokenSecret=thisismyaccesstokensecret
debug=true
http.prettyDebug=true
```

I am initiating a Twitter stream like so:

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
twitterStream.addListener(listener);

twitterStream.sample();
```

I am able to get the application to run if I manually set it using `ConfigurationBuilder`, but I would like for the application to read my properties file instead. Is there something else that I have to do in order to get my project to recognize the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely overlooked my accessToken and accessTokenSecret. `oath` should be `oauth`. Let this be a lesson: don't code too late into the night.

For what it's worth, I put the `twitter4j.properties` file in the root of my project folder and it works perfectly.